# Scraping with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape this:

```
<a id="pa1">Site1</a>
<font size="-1">Text1</font><br />
<font size="-1" color="green">Text2</font><br />
```

I get get to pa1 easily..but I want to get to the two fonts that come after.. So I used this:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($document);

foreach ($html->find('#pa1>font') as $e) {
    $this->check_line_two = $this->process_array_elements($e->innertext);
}

foreach ($html->find('#pa1>font>font') as $e) {
    $this->check_line_three = $this->process_array_elements($e->innertext);
}
```

Both didn't work. How can I get the next element with simple html dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like feeela said, those font elements are not descendants of the anchor. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($html->find('#pa1') as $e) {
    $firstFontElement = $e->next_sibling();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I guess that was the best solution

Answer (score 2):

There is no descendant `font`-tag within `#pa1`.

What you are obviously searching for is the sibling selector `+`: `#pa1 + font`. But I don't know if it is supported by the library you are using.

Please read their documentation: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd What doesn't work for you? Reading the docs?

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you are trying to scrap, why don't you just select the font tag.

```
foreach ($html->find('font') as $e) {
    $this->check_line_two = $this->process_array_elements($e->innertext);
}
```

Or is there a possibility that more font tags are present in the document?

Comment: you could have more than one font in the document